# VS 2019 and SAP HANA data source

Tags: visual-studio-2019, datasource, hana

I have just updated to Visual Studio 2019 and I go to add a connection to SAP HANA.  SAP HANA Client is installed on my computer.  When I go to add the connection, the driver doesn't show up.  It shows up in VS 2015 still, just not in 2019.

This is 2015:

[image]

In 2019, that SAP HANA datasource is missing.  How do I get it to show up in VS 2019?

Comment: Maybe there's a difference in x86 and x64 versions of VS and installed drivers?

Comment: It appears that the HANA client i have installed is x64.  Both Visual Studios are x86, so why would one shows it and the other not?